# Program stuck when trying to add new buttons after dynamical button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()

    Dim patiekalai = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai1 = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai2 = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai3 = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai4 = New Button()

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai)
    patiekalai.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    patiekalai.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai1)
    patiekalai1.Location = New Point(0, 50)
    patiekalai1.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai2)
    patiekalai2.Location = New Point(0, 100)
    patiekalai2.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai3)
    patiekalai3.Location = New Point(0, 150)
    patiekalai3.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai4)
    patiekalai4.Location = New Point(0, 200)
    patiekalai4.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    patiekalai.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Karštieji patiekalai.jpg")
    AddHandler patiekalai.Click, AddressOf Patiekalai_Click
    patiekalai1.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Salotos.jpg")
    patiekalai2.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Desertai.jpg")
    patiekalai3.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Užkandžiai.jpg")
    patiekalai4.Image = Image.FromFile("../M/Sriubos.jpg")
End Sub
Private Sub Patiekalai(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    Dim patiekalai5 = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai6 = New Button()
    Dim patiekalai7 = New Button()
    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai5)
    patiekalai5.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    patiekalai5.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai6)
    patiekalai6.Location = New Point(0, 50)
    patiekalai6.Size = New Size(80, 50)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai7)
    patiekalai7.Location = New Point(0, 100)
    patiekalai7.Size = New Size(80, 50)
End Sub

Private Sub Patiekalai_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub
End Class
```

I get

```
Private Sub Patiekalai_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub
```

after program fails and stuck.

I am trying to add new buttons after patiekalai button is clicked.

Comment: Please do not add tags like `VB` or `vb.net` in the title.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood your question properly, but the method associated with the button click event (`Patiekalai_Click`) does throw an exception. Thus, the program is expected to crash after you click on the button. This is precisely what your code is instructed to do (with the line `Throw New NotImplementedException`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add a handler in code manually by using `AddHandler` to attach the delegate.

```
AddHandler patiekalai6.click, addressof Patiekalai_Click
```

for example. you will need to add a handler like this for each of the buttons.

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(patiekalai7)
patiekalai7.Location = New Point(0, 100)
patiekalai7.Size = New Size(80, 50)
AddHandler patiekalai7.click, addressof Patiekalai_Click
```

Comment: Where add addhandler code shoud be? I am very confused atm. Maybe u can show me fixed code? :)

Comment: You can include in in your code right after you set the properties of each button. All it does is attach the event handler delegate to the new button that was just created.  I added an additional example to the code above.  You will need to add the handler like this for each of the new buttons you create.

Comment: I get AddHandler patiekalai.Click, AddressOf (Patiekalai_Click()) After I put code and get errors Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub Patiekalai_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.
Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Private Sub Patiekalai_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'

Comment: Remove the brackets: `AddHandler patiekalai.Click, AddressOf Patiekalai_Click`. `AddressOf` is an operator, not a method call. You don't want to call `Patiekalai_Click`, you need its address, therefore no brackes after `Patiekalai_Click`!

Comment: @Olivier Thanks, I was typing from memory, no code in front of me.  I forgot it doesn't take parens.  Corrected examples.